# How to await the dispatch of the action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

In the redux, i have a (count, remote Count)
I set it by default 0 for both!

The main idea is comparing if the count equals the remote count I want to dispatch an action 'true/false' that Locks the App

In home screen get a remote count from API then save it in redux store, it's saved well

but I have an if statement that checks if count == remote count I lock the app

So this statement invokes before I save remote count I guess although I add it in then()

Home screen

```
  getRemoteCount = async () => {
    try {
      let response = await API.get('/number/subsribtion');
      let remoteCount = response.data.number;
      this.props.saveRemoteCount(remoteCount); // it's saved the remote count! 
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };




 componentDidMount() {
    const {remoteCount, count} = this.props;
    this.getRemoteCount().then(() => {
      if (count == remoteCount) {
        console.log('count', count); 
        console.log('remoteCount', remoteCount);//it's log 0!! so the next line invoke!
        this.props.isAppLock(true);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: iu u are updating with redux why u expecting  count i than ??? this.getRemoteCount().then(()

Comment: Youre redux will update count, use that count..in render

Answer (score 1):

Use render to get updated count. componentDidMount run when component mounts for the first time. Save the count on `redux store` and `mapToState` in the component.

```
class C {
  getRemoteCount = async () => {
    try {
      let response = await API.get("/number/subsribtion");
      let remoteCount = response.data.number;
      this.props.saveRemoteCount(remoteCount); // it's saved the remote count!
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getRemoteCount();
  }
  render() {
    const { remoteCount, count } = this.props;
    if (count == remoteCount) {
      console.log("count", count);
      console.log("remoteCount", remoteCount); //it's log 0!! so the next line invoke!
      this.props.isAppLock(true);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, I already save count in redux store "at the first time it's 0" and remote count 0, So in the render methods will not await the `getRemoteCount()` to complete and updated the remote count so actually will dispatch `.isAppLock(true)` So that's why I added if statement in `then()` I want after remote count updated from 0 to 30 for example then check and do the other stuff, r u understand the point?

Comment: I can solve the issue by setting `remoteCount` in the initial state to number large than 0 so it will not dispatch any action cuz count != remoteCount but I want to understand it why not work in this way?

Comment: i dont see purpose of wring in componentDidMount.. unless u use it to stop side effect.. glad u solve it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dispatch async` function using redux thunk.

1. Install redux thunk.
2. Use as a middleware inside store.

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

3. Use it for dispatch async actions.

```
return async dispatch=>{ let res= await authLogin(data)}
```